# How to call a static method on a class Template method?

Tags: swift, swift3

I try to call a class method on a generic `T: BaseModel` where T can be a subclass of BaseModel.
For example `Car`.
In the case T should be `Car`, I want my class method to be called on the `Car` class.

However, It always ends up calling the BaseModel class method instead.

```
class func parse<T: BaseModel>(json: JSON, context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> T? {
   return T.classParseMethod(json: json) //This never calls the Car.classParseMethod()
}
```

where

```
let carObject = parse(json:json, context:context) as? Car
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The casting is done after the function call so the generic constraint resolves to T = BaseModel. You want the function to know of the type so it can properly resolve the generic constraint:

```
func parse<T: BaseModel>(_ str: String) -> T? {
    print(T.Type.self) // should print like: Car.Type
    return T.parse(str) as? T
}

// Make the desired type known to swift
let car: Car? = parse("My Car Format String")
```

Comment: Anyone know why you still have to cast to T (`T.parse(str) as? T`) in the generic parse method?

Comment: Doesn't work in my code. Maybe because I'm working is class functions.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that seems to work is:

to add

```
func myFunc<T: BaseModel>(_ type: T.Type,..) -> T? {
  type.aClassFunc()
{
```

If I call the following, it works.

```
if let obj = myFunc(Car.self, ...) {
   // obj will be of type Car
}
```

It seems really too much just to achieve this but there might be an underlying reason for it.